# LogCat - E/SELinux: avc: denied { find }

Tags: android, logcat, permission-denied, selinux

LogCat shows me this message every second

Any ideas on how to repair this error?

```
2021-01-17 17:41:08.905 174-174/? E/SELinux: avc:  denied  { find } for pid=25449 uid=2000 name=car_service scontext=u:r:shell:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:default_android_service:s0 tclass=service_manager permissive=0
2021-01-17 17:41:09.903 174-174/? E/SELinux: avc:  denied  { find } for pid=25455 uid=2000 name=car_service scontext=u:r:shell:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:default_android_service:s0 tclass=service_manager permissive=0
```

Comment: I get it 5 times a second. It's problematic because logcat removes old entries as new ones get in.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a [SELinux](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux) denial. You can ignore it as it won't affect your app. There isn't anything you can do about it (at a user level).

If you are using a custom ROM, the maintainer needs to update their sepolicy.

If you are the maintainer, there are detailed guides on how to understand the denials and write the appropriate the rules for them. One such guide is https://msfjarvis.dev/posts/understanding-and-resolving-selinux-denials-on-android/

If you have any specific doubts in writing the correct rule for this, you can update the question

Answer (score 0):

I had a lot of such errors on my Realme 8i with Android 11 (on a stock firmare) but for another name - `tethering`:

```
2023-01-01 15:34:33.134 501 501 system E SELinux : avc:  denied  { find } for pid=22576
 uid=10219 name=tethering scontext=u:r:permissioncontroller_app:s0:c219,c256,c512,c768
 tcontext=u:object_r:tethering_service:s0 tclass=service_manager permissive=0
```

Disabling `Tethering hardware acceleration` in `Developer options` immediately stopped such spam.